# Como modelar Produto/Estoque?

Tags: java, modelagem

Comecei uma modelagem para Produtos pensando nos mesmo como:

- Comprados para Revender
- Produzidos para Venda
- Perecíveis ou não

Até aí tudo bem, mas quando comecei a pensar em controle de estoque baseado nesse modelo minha cabeça deu um nó, por conta do controle de Lotes de Fabricação e por conta de ser ou não perecível.

Abaixo a primeira versão da minha entidade Produto.

Uma breve explicação sobre os relacionamentos:

Fornecedor se refere aos produtos adquiridos para revenda

Empresa para os produtos produzidos pela minha empresa

MedidaProduto uma tabela que guarda se o produto é medido em KG, L ou P, PP, M etc.

```
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    @Basic
    private int ativo;
    @Column(length=400)
    @Basic
    private String caminhoImagem;
    @Basic
    private double largura;
    @Basic
    private double peso;
    @Column(length=70)
    @Basic
    private String cor;
    @Basic
    private String valorCompra;
    @Column(length=150)
    @Basic
    private String nome;
    @Basic
    private double profundidade;
    @Column(length=200)
    @Basic
    private String descricao;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = TipoProdutoEnum.class)
    private TipoProdutoEnum tipoProdutoEnum1;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Basic
    private Date dataAtualizacao;
    @Basic
    private double altura;
    @Basic
    private String valorVenda;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = MedidaProduto.class)
    private MedidaProduto medidaProduto;
    @Basic
    private double quantidadeMaxima;
    @Basic
    private double quantidadeMinima;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Basic
    private Date dataDesativacao;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_produto",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_produto",sequenceName="seq_produto",allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    private double quantidadeAtual;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Fornecedor.class)
    private Fornecedor fornecedor;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Empresa.class)
    private Empresa empresa;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Basic
    private Date dataCadastro;
}
```

Quando comecei a pensar em controle de estoque vi que misturei um pouco os conceitos e na questão de controle de produção estou completamente perdido.

Comment: vc pode ter alguma flag que identifique  que uma venda seja uma revenda mas na prática, venda e revenda são a mesma coisa. sugiro começar a “descomplicar” o problema por aí. Quanto aos perecíveis não pense muito agora porque vai dar nó na cabeça mesmo. O importante é modelar de forma modular, ou seja onde poderá encaixar e desencaixar regras diversas sem afetar a estrutura. Um exemplo de como perecíveis vão se complicando é “geladeira”, "congelador", “seco”.  Isso influencia no despacho/empacotamento. Outro é, peso irregular. Um corte de carne nunca é perfeito em relação ao peso. E por aí vai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, misturou os conceitos. Produto é produto, lote é lote. Tudo que você trata de forma geral, abstrata, é produto. Pense no produto como um documento que fala sobre o produto. Ele não tem relação com itens físicos. Pelo menos esse é o entendimento na maior parte das modelagens.

Nesse documento até pode existir uma informação da quantidade existente de unidades dele. Eu disse "pode" porque há modelagens onde isso está errado, você pode ter armazéns, por exemplo. Alguns acham que até mesmo quando você tem apenas um armazém (em indústrias é raríssimo ter apenas um, e a descrição da pergunta parece indicar que tem pelo menos dois) o ideal é que esta informação esteja no local mais adequado. Não posso dizer o que é melhor para o seu caso.

Mas se tem quantidades de lotes produzidos, se esses lotes tem validade, controle de qualidade específico, tem que controlar isso de forma separada. Note que aí ainda temos algo abstrato, porque o lote não deixa de ser só um documento.

Você só entra no concreto quando fala da unidade em si (ainda que o cadastro não deixe de ser apenas um documento). E há casos em que é preciso cadastrar cada unidade produzida, caso típico quando precisa do número de série (não é qualquer uso de série que precisa do cadastro individual).

Outro exemplo do que pode não ser bem como pensa: é comum o produto ter vários fornecedores possíveis (ainda que a unidade só tenha um).

Alguns tipos usados nos dados me assustam um pouco, principalmente o valor de venda ser `String`.

Você talvez esteja modelando em cima de algo não real. Isso é sempre complicado, porque em tese qualquer coisa pode ser válida. Não existe certo ou errado em modelagem no abstrato total. Com a necessidade real é que dá pra dizer o que é certo ou não, e sempre para aquela situação do momento.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Show, ja deu pra esclarecer algumas coisas. O valor de venda como String foi só esquecimento mesmo.